# Determining equivalence of relationship between more than one regression

Tags: r, regression, time-series

I've got a data set which has volume of mail sent from 2001-2012, recorded by age group. That is, for seven different age groups, I have each age group's annual volume of mail sent over that time period.

I've run seven regressions in R--one for each age group--which simply regress volume of mail sent on time. My hypothesis is that these seven relationships are structurally similar (that is, while the coefficients may be different due to the initial volume of mail having been different for each age group in 2001, the *relationship* between volume of mail sent and time is not significantly different since 2001), or that there are no significant "age group effects."

I don't think this can be accomplished through a Chow Test, since the dependent variables are different in all seven regressions (maybe there's a way to run a Chow Test on these data if they are pooled?). Does anybody know of a way I might be able to do this, particularly in R?

Comment: can't you regress the variables to an intercept and work with the residuals? Then you won't have a problem with the initial level, or maybe I'm missunderstanding. Have you tried this?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you're suggesting. Would you mind elaborating a bit? Thanks!

Comment: If you regress all your variables on a constant, $Y_t=\beta 1+\epsilon_t$, You will take away the intercept of you series and you residuals will just have mean 0. Hence the initial value of all your variables will be the same, 0.

Comment: Would running the regressions as before, but centering each regression around 0 be the same thing? That is, force R to acknowledge 0 as the intercept.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I guess that would be the same as including an intercept in the initial regression. Now I'm not sure what you mean anymore, with " the initial volume of mail having been different for each age group" if an intercept doesn't help. So what you are trying to determine, is if the coefficient of a time trend would be the same in all the different age groups?

Comment: You're correct. More specifically, I'd like to see if the coefficient of the time trend would be significantly different or not across different age groups. I'd tried having the intercept as 0 and comparing the various results, but was wondering if there was a more rigorous test one could run to determine this.